# how to center align the read more button - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have some problems center aligning the Read More button. How can I center align the read more button?

```
.moretag {
color: #404040 !important;
}
.moretag:hover {
  color: #fa5742 !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't include links; paste the relevant HTML and css code instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  You should also post your code instead of links.

```
.moretag img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

also since you're using an image for the button. You should crop the image closer to the button so it can be truly centered.